# Cloning 20 machines a week: how to clone to variable size destination drives (small to large)

Tags: system-installation, clonezilla, replication

I work with a non-profit that installs an Ubuntu variant on machines every week, thousands per year.  However, the destination hard drive size varies depending on what's donated.

The current install procedure uses a CD, then hand editing of settings.  What's a better way?

If a small master drive is instead cloned, how can the partition size be adjusted for each final target drive's size?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?  Installation taking too long wall time?  Installation requiring too much attention?   Considered automating an OEM installation, perhaps even from the network?

Comment: Addressing: inconsistent hand steps after CD install, overall time taken, and (compared to CD install) ability to pre-install updates.  The non-profit has few tech resources, so it has to be dead simple. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Too broad?  I wrote that question to be broadly useful @mdpc

Comment: Consider looking into automated installs so they can just boot on the DVD/USB and it automatically scrubs and reinstalls Ubuntu by providing an answer to every question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done with SBCs (raspberrypi, odroid, etc) what they do is add a line to /etc/rc.local, something like;

```
if [ -f init.sh ] ; then init.sh; fi
```

and init.sh resizes the partition ext4 (with or without lvm) then deletes itself.

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/V_a/L_a
resize2fs /dev/V_a/L_a
rm init.sh
```

to copy an image use dd;

```
dd if=my.img of=/dev/sdb bs=10m; sync
```

Comment: What's best for the cloning itself?

Comment: I'll probably recommend clonezilla, but the dd does help fill out your answer. Thanks,